# Project with Match in aggregate not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to fetch data based on some match condition. First I've tried this:
Here ending_date is full date format

```
    Offer.aggregate([ 
    { 
        $match: { 
            carer_id : req.params.carer_id,
            status : 3
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : { year: { $year : "$ending_date" }, month: { $month : "$ending_date" }}, 
            count : { $sum : 1 }
        }
    }], 
    function (err, res)
    { if (err) ; // TODO handle error 
         console.log(res); 
    });
```

which gives me following output:

```
[ { _id: { year: 2015, month: 11 }, count: 2 } ]
```

Now I want to check year also, so I am trying this:

```
    Offer.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            myyear: {$year: "$ending_date"}
        }
    },
    { 
        $match: { 
            carer_id : req.params.carer_id,
            status : 3,
            $myyear : "2015"
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : { year: { $year : "$ending_date" }, month: { $month : "$ending_date" }}, 
            count : { $sum : 1 }
        }
    }], 
    function (err, res)
    { if (err) ; // TODO handle error 
         console.log(res); 
    });
```

which gives me following output:

```
 []
```

as you can see, _id has 2015 as a year, so when I match year it should be come in array. But I am getting null array. Why this?

Is there any other way to match only year form whole datetime?

Here is the sample data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56348e7938b1ab3c382d3363"
    },
    "carer_id": "55e6f647f081105c299bb45d",
    "user_id": "55f000a2878075c416ff9879",
    "starting_date": {
        "$date": "2015-10-15T05:41:00.000Z"
    },
    "ending_date": {
        "$date": "2015-11-19T10:03:00.000Z"
    },
    "amount": "850",
    "total_days": "25",
    "status": 3,
    "is_confirm": false,
    "__v": 0
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "563b5747d6e0a50300a1059a"
    },
    "carer_id": "55e6f647f081105c299bb45d",
    "user_id": "55f000a2878075c416ff9879",
    "starting_date": {
        "$date": "2015-11-06T04:40:00.000Z"
    },
    "ending_date": {
        "$date": "2015-11-16T04:40:00.000Z"
    },
    "amount": "25",
    "total_days": "10",
    "status": 3,
    "is_confirm": false,
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: `$myyear : "2015"` matches a string, while your document seems to store a number.

Comment: myyear comes from project. I thing it returns string only

Comment: I've also tried with $myyear : 2015, but same result

Comment: please include some sample data in your question

Comment: ok. let me edit the question

Comment: Why do your field names start with `$`? This goes against the naming rules. In fact, I am getting this error when trying to insert: `Error: field names cannot start with $ [$oid]`.

Comment: you mean in sample data? its mongolab data format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot to project the fields that you're using in `$match` and `$group` later on. For a quick fix, use this query instead:

```js
Offer.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        myyear: { $year: "$ending_date" },
        carer_id: 1,
        status: 1,
        ending_date: 1
    }
},
{ 
    $match: { 
        carer_id: req.params.carer_id,
        myyear: 2015,
        status: 3
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: { $year: "$ending_date" },
            month: { $month: "$ending_date" }
        }, 
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}], 
function (err, res)
{
    if (err) {} // TODO handle error 
    console.log(res); 
});
```

That said, [Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/) explained how to make a better query in her answer. I think you should try and use her approach instead.

Comment: Hers actually. The clear thing the OP was trying to do here is "match the year" by projecting the year portion of the date. So that is what I was addressing as well as the missing fields.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Oops, sorry, edited now. Gender assumptions are never a good thing :) Good job on addressing the issues with the query!

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko: Can I use $myyear : "2015" in match function?because when I write it, I get blank array []. Although, Blakes Seven approach is correct, but It seems my approach is also correct logically

Comment: @Arvaan edited my answer to include `myyear` in the `$match`. As I mentioned previously, using a string to match a number will not work.

Comment: ok sorry my bad, ultimately it was my error that I didn't mention status and carer_id in project

Comment: @Arvaan It does not matter if it "works" when it is not really the right thing to do. Adding in a `$project` stage requires all documents in the collection ( current results ) to be processed to output the set fields. The alternate to just `$match` returns the same data without calculation.

Comment: @Arvaan yep. Anyway, since you were presented with a better answer, which BlakesSeven took the time to explain in detail, I would suggest that you try to understand it and use it in your code.

Comment: Yes, I am also going to try Blackseven code, I appreciate both of you for your effort and explaination

Comment: This doesnot returns the result, can anyone help me?

Comment: How can I use $project in the last stage?

Answer (score 13):

You are doing so many things wrong here, that it really warrants an explanation so hopefully you learn something.

### Its a Pipeline

---

It's the most basic concept but the one people do not pick up on the most often ( and even after continued use ) that the aggregation "pipeline" is just exactly that, being "piped" processes that feed input into the each stage as it goes along. Think "unix pipe" `|`:

```js
ps -ef | grep mongo | tee out.txt
```

You've seen something similar before no doubt, and it's the basic concept that output from the first thing goes to the next thing and then that manipulates to give input to the next thing and so on.

So heres the basic problem with what you are asking:

```js
    {
        $project: {
            myyear: {$year: "$ending_date"}
        }
    },
    { 
        $match: { 
            carer_id : req.params.carer_id,
            status : 3,
            $myyear : "2015"
        }
    },
```

Consider what `$project` does here. You specify fields you want in the output and it "spits them out", and possibly with manipulation. Does it output these fields in "addition" the the fields in the document? **No It does not**. Only what you ask to come out actually comes out and can be used in the following pipeline stage(s).

The `$match` here essentially asks for fields that are no longer present, because you only asked for one thing in the output. The same problem occurs further down as again you ask for fields you removed earlier and there simply is nothing to reference, but also everything was already removed by a `$match` that could not match anything.

Also, that is not how field projections work as you have entered

### So just use a range for the date

---

```js
        { "$match": { 
            "carer_id" : req.params.carer_id,
            "status" : 3,
            "ending_date": { 
                "$gte": new Date("2015-01-01"), 
                "$lt": new Date("2016-01-01")
            }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "year": { "$year": "$ending_date" }, 
                "month": { "$month": "$ending_date" }
            }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}
```

Why? Because it just makes sense. If you want to match the "year" then supply the date range for the whole year. We could play silliness with `$redact` to match on the extracted year value, but that is just wasted processing time.

Doing this way is the fastest to process and can actually use an index to process faster. So don't otherthink the problem and just ask for the date range you want.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand that is the "wrong way" to just filter out matches within the current year. As I said, we could do that using `$redact` as opposed to `$project` and therefore not even mess around with selecting fields, but it is not necessary. The whole "myyear" is not required. And you are still trying to match on a "string". It's not a string. Take another good look and try to understand the point of selecting the date range instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your aggregation to work you have to use $addFields instead of $project in order to keep `status` and `carer_id` in the object you pass to the $match

```
{
        $addFields: {
            myyear: {$year: "$ending_date"}
        }
    },
    { 
        $match: { 
            carer_id : req.params.carer_id,
            status : 3,
            $myyear : "2015"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

**The correct query will look like this, You can use something relatable:**

```
Offer.aggregate([
   { $match:{ isPinSet:true } },
   { $project:{ "_id":1,"pVersion":1,isPinSet:1 } }
])
```